# setTimeout takes priority on an entire VueJS method

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, methods, hierarchy

I'm currently writing a visual and behavioral emulation of Whatsapp web.

One of the taks of the project is to add a delay between the ENTER key press to send a message and the message being shown in the chatbox.

I'm currently trying to achieve this behavior via these lines of code:

VueJS

```
sentMessage(i){
  const newMessage = this.text;

  this.text = "";

  setTimeout(() =>{
    this.contacts[this.currentContactChat].messages.push(
      {
        date: "10/01/2020 15:50:00",
        message: newMessage,
        status: "sent",
      });
  },
  1000);
},
```

html

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control border border-start-0" placeholder="Scrivi un messaggio" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
   v-model="text"
   @keyup.enter="sentMessage(i)">
</div>
```

What I'm expecting is the following in chronological order:

1. the `const newMessage = this.text` stores the text input from the input tag on the screen;
2. the `this.text = ""` immediately clears the input tag on the screen from any message written inside of it;
3. the timeout starts, waiting for 1 second before pushing the new message on the chat array of messages hence the message appears after 1 second in the chatbox.

However, what really happens is the following:

1. `const newMessage = this.text` store the message
2. the timeout starts, wait 1 second, and then clears the input tag text and pushes `newMessage` in the array at the same time.

The whole method behaves as if the setTimeout takes over the whole code of the method and dictates the priority of which events are performed.

Is there a way to prevent this or to force the intended order of events?

Edit: I can link the whole repo or give you a live link via raw.githack if needed!

Comment: Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem. You'll have better chance to resolve it if it's workable demo that can be instantly debugged like stackblitz. You're potentially misusing v-model. Check what it means in the docs. Either use only it to work with a field and do whatever sentMessage does in a watcher, or remove it and do two-way binding manually. v-model together with `@` or `:value` == bad.

Comment: if the code you've shown is the exact code you have, then what you describe is not possible. That unused `i` argument makes me think something else is afoot